# Controller Action incorrectly returns status code 200 instead of 204

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1

I'm developing a REST-Api based on Asp.net Core MVC 1.1.3 If an action has no return type my client library expects a status code 204 (no content)
This is my action:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("")]
public async Task Update([FromBody]ApiResourceUpdateDto dto)
{
    await _repo.Update(dto.Name, dto.Enabled, dto.DisplayName, dto.Description);
}
```

As this method doesn't return anything it should return a status code of 204 (no-content). However if I test this method I will get a status code of 200 although the body is empty. I also tried switching to `void` instead of `Task` but it didn't change anything.

```
Request URL:http://localhost:5000/api/apiresource
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:5000
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: If you want to return 204, then return 204, otherwise it will default to 200.

Comment: I think its correct because your request just succeeded without any error so 200. For 204 you may have to tell action to return that specific HTTP code.

Comment: Thank you, of course I can always set the status code with `Response.StatusCode = 204;`. However WebApi 2 behaved exactly the way I described, I wonder why they changed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the [`NoContentResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.nocontentresult) to return HTTP 204 Status Code. Since the rewrite, you have to be a little more explicit with what you are returning because of the merging of the two frameworks from the previous versions. A controller can be either web api or normal MVC so there is no way to automatically infer which type it is.

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromBody]ApiResourceUpdateDto dto) {
    await _repo.Update(dto.Name, dto.Enabled, dto.DisplayName, dto.Description);
    return new NoContentResult();
}
```

Or you can even use `return NoContent();`

Comment: you can even use `return NoContent();`

Comment: @NickN. I will include it in the answer. Thanks.